# Remove adjacent duplicate characters in a String(java) i.e input:aaaabbbccdbbaae output: abcdbae

Tags: java, string

my code does not give expected output,but dry run works fine.please give a look where is the problem

```
public static StringBuffer singleOccurence(String s)
{
 StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(s);
 int length=s.length();


 for(int i=0; i< length ; i++)
 {
  for(int j=i; i<length&&j<length ; j++)
  {
    if(sb.charAt(i)!=sb.charAt(j+1)) 
         i=j+1;
    else
    sb.deleteCharAt(j+1);
   } 
 }

 return sb;
}
```

also gives StringIndexOutOfBounds

Comment: You're deleting characters from the StringBuffer, which makes it shorter. Your loops run until they reach the *original* length of s, but as soon as you call sb.deleteCharAt it'll be shorter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your method is doing a lot of unnecessary work.

The problem can be solved by iterating over the string once and comparing each character to the one that precedes it:

```
public static StringBuilder singleOccurence(String s)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (s.length() > 0) {
        char prev = s.charAt(0);
        sb.append(prev);
        for (int i = 1; i < s.length(); ++i) {
            char cur = s.charAt(i);
            if (cur != prev) {
                sb.append(cur);
                prev = cur;
            }
        }
    }
    return sb;
}
```

This method has linear time complexity.

Comment: I agree. For someone learning Java your answer is better. For actually using Java I'd prefer mine :)

Answer (score 4):

I would use a regex:

```
String input = "aaaabbbccdbbaae";
String regex = "(.)(\\1)+"; // matches any character followed by the same one(s)
String output = input.replaceAll(regex, "$1");
System.out.println(output); // abcdbae
```

Your method would be:

```
public static String singleOccurence(String s) {
    return s.replaceAll("(.)(\\1)+", "$1");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is to traverse string from end to start:

```
public static StringBuffer singleOccurence(String s)
{
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(s);        
    for (int i = sb.length() - 2; i >= 0; i--)
        if (sb.charAt(i) == sb.charAt(i + 1))
             sb.deleteCharAt(i + 1);
    return sb;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I do not have Java IDE, I think idea of algorithm is clear from this code. What is wrong with it? Feel free to correct obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds a lot like a negative lookahead to me:

```
 String input = "aaaaabbbbccccddd";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.)(?!\\1)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

    while(m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    String reg;
    String input;
    String output;
    reg    = "(.)(\\1)+";
    input  = "aaaabbbccdbbaae";
    output = input.replaceAll(reg,"$1");
    System.out.println("Input :"+input);
    System.out.println("Output:"+output);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `replaceAll` method with a `regex`

```
string result = myString.replaceAll(/([a-z])\1+/ig, "$1");
```

what this `regex` does is that it matches any alpha character `[a-z]` that is repeated which is triggered by the part `\1+`

the flags in the regex (after the last `/`) indicate that it should search the whole string (the `g` flag) and it should ignore the case (the `i` flag). you might not need the `g` flag since here we are using `replaceAll`.

here, we are replacing with `$1` which means, replace with the first matched group.
since we have parentheses around the `[a-z]`, the `$1` will be the matched character.

this all ends up meaning that, find repeated characters in the string, while ignoring the case and replace them with that character.

Answer (score 0):

public class RemoveAdjacentLetters {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter any word: "); // Inputting the word
    String str = scanner.nextLine();
    for (int i = 1; i < str.length(); i++) { // from 2nd letter
        if (str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(i - 1)) { // comparing adjacent
                                                    // letters

            str = str.substring(0, i - 1) + str.substring(i + 1); // eliminating
                                                                    // 1st
                                                                    // duplicates
            System.out.println(str);
            i = 0;                // i=0 because I need to check for all possible adjacent letters.. 

        }
    }
    if (str.length() == 0) {
        System.out.println("Empty String");
    } 
    scanner.close();
}
```

}

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: I had written a program to reduce a string as much as possible by following rule  
 for example “aabccddd”… just remove the adjacent letters with same value as much as possible… 
 aabccddd -> bccddd
 bccddd -> bddd
 bddd -> bd
 Suppose while reducing atlast you get bb -> print empty string for that scenario..
The logic is simple I am just comparing the 2nd and 1st char, if they are same i will remove them.. Else I had to compare 3rd and 2nd.. And repeat till the end...

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReverseSkip {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the Word or Sentence");
    str =in.nextLine();
    String revStr ="null";

    char [] chars = str.toCharArray();
    char [] reversedChars = new char[chars.length];

    reversedChars[reversedChars.length - 1] = chars[0];


    int r = reversedChars.length - 2;
    for(int i = 1 ; i < chars.length ; i++ ){
        if(chars[i] != chars[i-1]){
            reversedChars[r] = chars[i];
            r--;
        }
    }

    revStr = new String(Arrays.copyOfRange(reversedChars, r+1, reversedChars.length));

    System.out.println(revStr);
}
```

}

Comment: Could you give some description, to answer?

Comment: Give Input using Scanner Class, and  count the char and make new array 
 of same count using reversed char.Then put the last char to first .Now check the last char with the beside character if same remove it using i-1 and so on.now print the output

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to solve in Java. You just have to take  a StringBuffer.
This is the complete code:

```
public class Test3 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "aaaabbbccdbbaae";
    StringBuffer sbr = new StringBuffer();
    int i = 0 ;
    while(i < str.length()) {
        if(sbr.length() == 0 ) sbr.append(str.charAt(i));
        if(str.charAt(i) == sbr.charAt(sbr.length() -1)) {i++ ;}
        else {sbr.append(str.charAt(i)); i++;}
    }//while
System.out.println(sbr);
}

}//end1
```

This is the complete solution in Python :(Different Idea)

```
def lis(a):
    list1 = [] 
    # put the characters in the list
    [list1.append(ch)  for ch in a]
    print(list1)
    # moving backwards from last element i.e.len(a) -1 to first element 0 and step is -1
    for i in range(len(list1) - 1 , 0 , -1):
        # delete the repeated element
        if list1[i] == list1[i - 1]: del list1[i]

    return ''.join(list1)    


a = "Protiijaayii"
# output Protijayi
print(lis(a))
```